# In SQL how to ignore passed null values in a select statement

Tags: sql

I need to have both SQL's return the same result. In the second statement I need it ignore a passed null value maybe with an IF statement if CITY is NULL then do not consider CITY.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM DB.TABLE
WHERE CONTAINS (SUPPLIER,'STARBCUKS')
    AND CONTAINS (CITY,'LOS ANGLES');
```

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM DB.TABLE
WHERE CONTAINS (SUPPLIER,'STARBUCKS')
    AND CONTAINS (CITY,'');
```

Comment: `TOP` is SQL Server specific, MySQL uses LIMIT, please tag correctly your question

Comment: `''` isn't a "null value." Do you mean a blank string?

Comment: sorry, yes a blank string

Comment: I assume the string is coming in as a parameter or something? Have you tried anything to solve the problem? If so, what issues did you run into?

Comment: yes, the string would be coming in as variable from a user. the user might chose not to enter a value for city leaving it blank

Comment: User a variable for @city and change the last line to this: `AND (CONTAINS (CITY,@city) OR ISNULL(@city, '') = '');`

Comment: Looks like you're after a catch-all query, a bad practice. Just exclude the whole `and contains(city, @city)` if the variable is blank or null.

Comment: Does **[this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/puCphQY6SJbNJytt48FUJY/1)** help?

Answer (score 1):

You've said the value is coming in from a user. Given that, you have at least two options:

1. In the code executing the query, branch and either execute the query with the `CONTAINS` (if the supplied value isn't blank) or without it (if the supplied value is blank). That way, the query being run has only the things in it that it needs.
2. If for some reason you can't do that, you can fall back on logic, like:

   ```sql
   SELECT TOP 1 * 
   FROM DB.TABLE
   WHERE CONTAINS (SUPPLIER, @supplierParam)
       AND (@cityParam = '' OR CONTAINS (CITY, @cityParam));
   ```

   That way, if `@cityParam` is `''`, the first half of the `OR` is TRUE.

   *(I haven't handled `NULL` since if the value is coming from the user, I assume it can't be `NULL`. If it can, though, if this is T-SQL [as it seems to be], you can use `COALESCE(@cityParam, '')` in both places where `@cityParam` is used above.)*

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just remove the city altogether?

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM DB.TABLE
WHERE CONTAINS (SUPPLIER,'STARBCUKS');
```

You can add an `IIF` to determine the  from user input

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM DB.TABLE
WHERE CONTAINS (SUPPLIER,'STARBCUKS');
AND IIF(<city> = '', TRUE , CONTAINS (CITY,'<city>');
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_iif.asp

Comment: I don't know if CITY will have a value or be blank. if it is blank i want to execute the above if it has a value then I want to include it

Comment: Hi Leo, you could add an `IIF`. I've changed my answer

Answer (score -1):

I think this might work.

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO result_count FROM DB.TABLE
    WHERE CONTAINS (SUPPLIER_NAME,'STARBUCKS')
    AND CONTAINS (CITY,'');
    IF result_count = 0
    THEN
        SELECT TOP 1 * FROM DB.TABLE 
            WHERE CONTAINS (SUPPLIER_NAME,'STARBUCKS')
            AND CONTAINS (CITY,'LOS ANGELES');
    ELSE
        SELECT TOP 1 * FROM DB.TABLE
            WHERE CONTAINS (SUPPLIER_NAME,'STARBUCKS');
    END IF;
```